# How to rasterize 2D points on a 2D canvas with custom values?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, rasterizing

Given a list of points `x_coords,y_coords` and a their corresponding `values`, I want to rasterize it onto a 2D `canvas` with these specific `values`. Is there a python library to do this? As an attempt I was using `PIL`, however, it only allows me to fill with a single value:

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
draw.point([*zip(x_coords, y_coords)], fill=1) 

# Ideally I want to fill it with specific values:
# draw.point([*zip(x_coords, y_coords)], fill=values)
```

Comment: does your point cloud exist in some order, or is it really a set without order? how many points do you have? can you assume a fixed radius per "point"?

Comment: Sorry just saw this, there is no order. There are roughly 50000 points. What do you mean by fixed radius per point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: illustration]

sounds like exactly what you want, [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata). example code included. basically you need:

```py
# rearrange your coordinates into one array of rows
points = np.stack([x_coords, y_coords]).T

# the j-"notation" gives you 100 by 200 points in the 0..1 interval, or...
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:200j]

# this gives you the specified step
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:0.01, 0:1:0.01]

# resample point data according to grid
grid_z2 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
```

Comment: So this seems to interpolate for the entire canvas. I suppose I can just mask out the points to get the final product rasterized on the canvas?

Comment: Hmm, but then I need to determine what that mask is based on how the xy coordinates have been rasterized

Comment: I noticed the interpolation at the boundary has some weird artifacts if I don't mask it.

Comment: Also, seems to be quite slow, not a huge issue for my purposes but ideally something faster would be optimal.

Comment: something faster would be drawing points/disks, as you proposed in your question. that works best if your point cloud is somewhat evenly distributed, so distances between points can be adequately predicted and filled by fixed size disks/circles. if that's not the case, you would need a variable radius to cover variable distances, or live with gaps, or use the interpolation method, which does its best to fill in.

Comment: So for my application, it's fine to have gaps between the points. I just need to fill in that specific point with its specific value. Do you know of something that allows for custom fill values for drawing points?

Comment: assuming you want to paint grayscale, not in color, I would set individual pixels and then use morphology (grayscale) to widen those. opencv can draw circles but that probably takes more CPU, given you want to draw that many dots.